# How to get a dynamic row using subprocess?

Tags: python, pygtk, subprocess, rsync

I'm creating a python script that runs rsync using subprocess and then gets the stdout and print it.

But there is a problem. When rsync starts to upload files, it shows the current file, speed and so on on a dynamic row, which changes constantly.
This row is never printed using my script. How would I fix that?

You can find my complete script here: https://github.com/danielholm/BareShare/blob/master/bareshare.py

And a snippet:

```
self.rsyncRun = subprocess.Popen(["rsync","--bwlimit="+upload,"--stats","--progress","-azvv","-e","ssh",local,remotedir,"--log-file="+rsynclog], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
self.line = self.rsyncRun.stdout.readline()
rsyncM = self.line.rstrip()
self.labelR.set_label(rsyncM)
print "DEBUG: "+rsyncM
```

Answer (score 0):

You tried passing the argument stderr=subprocess.PIPE like the following:

```
self.rsyncRun = subprocess.Popen(["rsync","--bwlimit="+upload,"--stats","--progress","-azvv","-e","ssh",local,remotedir,"--log-file="+rsynclog], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

EDIT: You will then have to read from self.rsyncRun.stderr, instead of self.rsyncRun.stdout.

EDIT2: A more complete code sample is like this:

```
self.rsyncRun = subprocess.Popen(["rsync","--bwlimit="+upload,"--stats","--progress","-azvv","-e","ssh",local,remotedir,"--log-file="+rsynclog], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
outData, errData = self.rsyncRun.communicate()  # this will return the data read from stdout, and stderr
```

Then you can check outData, and errData to see if the progress is printed there. Of course, communicate() would not return until the process terminates, so if you looking to print out some live progress, that would not work.

Comment: Now the process wont die on exit..

  File "bareshare.py", line 217, in rsyncOutput
    self.line = self.rsyncRun.stderr.readline()
KeyboardInterrupt

Comment: If the stderr, or stdout buffer become full, the subprocess(rsync) will be blocked until the buffer is cleared. For most of the progressive console programs, when their output is captured. It will look like: ...1%,....2%.....2%.....3%.... and keep repeating, so I highly believe this is the case. In Linux the PIPE size is 4096Bytes, so this can get fill up easily. Did you try the Popen.communicate() function yet? (Read section 17.1.2 of http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html )

Comment: How do you mean I would use the popen.communicatte() function?

Comment: @DanielHolm, I just added an edit2 to explain how to use the communicate()

Comment: I'm back at this issue. And I need the output to be printed continuously. What would I use instead of .communicate()?

Answer (score 0):

Try running rsync with `-q` or omitting the `-progress` arguments, that will suppress the dynamic progress update.

Comment: But I want the transfer speed of current file.